# Breeze - Lazy load complex type

Tags: javascript, breeze

I'm trying to lazy load a complex type in breeze but cannot figure out a way to accomplish this.

The reason I would like to use a complex type and not the navigation way, is the service I have to consume is not doing CRUD the same way as breeze. I have to send one single object with all its subobjects (both scalar and non scalar) to a single service method responsible for storing data (insert/update/delete).

I tried to do this with navigation properties but this means I have to create an array of entities to send to an API controller, and there recreate the entire object. This would be difficult, but even more so because there are no foreign keys in the child objects (which is the case in all samples I've seen until now) making it a pain to map them again.

With complex types, I don't have this issue (or not that I'm aware of).

I have to consume an object structure like this:

1.Parent: product (class)

1.1Child: packages (array)

1.2Child: splitLevels (array)

1.2.1Grandchild: permissions (array)

1.2.1.1Grandgrandchild: pharmacies (array)

1.2.2Grandchild: splitLevel (class)

Packages are loaded together with the product, this works just fine.
Howevers, splitLevels are not included in this datacontract (since it requires too much data and will not be consulted that often). When requesting this data, a boolean is added to the product to indicate they have been loaded, from then on it is required to send them to the server as well.

When loading product, this results in an issue:
Object doesn't support property or method 'getProperty'

This is caused by the _initializeInstance method in breeze:

```
if (initFn) {
    if (typeof initFn === "string") {
        initFn = instance[initFn];
    }
    initFn(instance);
}
this.complexProperties && this.complexProperties.forEach(function (cp) {
    var ctInstance = instance.getProperty(cp.name);
    cp.dataType._initializeInstance(ctInstance);
});
```

The instance is empty, no properties can be fetched from it.

Is there any way to work around this?
Is there a way to use navigation properties without getting multiple entities; so I can send a single object without using this:

```
if (product.entityAspect.entityState.isUnchanged()) {
    product.entityAspect.setModified();
}

// Packages
var entitiesToSave = product.packages().slice();// copy

// Split Levels
if (product.storeSplitLevels) {
    product.splitLevelsLoaded(true);
    // TODO: Add split levels to entities to save
}

// Product Details
entitiesToSave.push(product);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information, I'm not entirely clear on what you are asking but we are planning on adding a function to the Breeze API for the EntityManager that will allow you to call an arbitrary endpoint with an arbitrary datastructure and have the result of the call, if any, be merged back into the EntityManager via a JsonResultsAdapter.

Until then you could accomplish some of this right now by bypassing the EntityManager.saveChanges and just using the Breeze ajax adapter directly to call your endpoint. Something like

```
var ajaxImpl = breeze.config.getAdapterInstance("ajax");
ajaxImpl.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: bundle,   // arbitrary data to server.
        success: function (httpResponse) {
            // perform custom client side code 
        },
        error: function (httpResponse) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry about this, my questions are:  
  
1. Is it possible to lazy load nested complex types; being an array containing complex types that contain other complex types. I can't get this to work (cfr the code block from breeze).

2. If not, is there a way to use navigation properties without having all entities at the same level but the same way the incoming datacontract defined them. But you actually answered this question with your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I followed your suggestion to create a custom bundle.

For other developers having the same issue, I did the following:

1. Create a custom unwrap function which provides the same functionality as the unwrap function in breeze, but extending it to contain the navigation properties as well.
2. Add a method to create a save bundle from an entity.

Code:

```
function createEntitySaveBundle(entity) {
    var rawEntity = unwrapInstance(entity);
    var entities = [];
    rawEntity.entityAspect = {
        entityTypeName: entity.entityType.name,
        defaultResourceName: entity.entityType.defaultResourceName,
        entityState: entity.entityAspect.entityState.name,
        autoGeneratedKey: {
            propertyName: entity.entityType.keyProperties[0].nameOnServer,
            autoGeneratedKeyType: entity.entityType.autoGeneratedKeyType.name
        }
    };
    entities.push(rawEntity);

    return { entities: entities, saveOptions: {} };
}

function unwrapInstance(entity) {
    var rawObject = {};
    var stype = entity.entityType || entity.complexType;
    var val;
    var entities;

    stype.dataProperties.forEach(function (dp) {
        if (dp.isUnmapped) {
            val = entity.getProperty(dp.name);
            val = transformValue(val, dp, false);
            if (val !== undefined) {
                rawObject.__unmapped = rawObject.__unmapped || {};
                // no name on server for unmapped props
                rawObject.__unmapped[dp.name] = val;
            }
        } else if (dp.isComplexProperty) {
            if (dp.isScalar) {
                rawObject[dp.nameOnServer] = unwrapInstance(entity.getProperty(dp.name));
            } else {
                entities = entity.getProperty(dp.name);
                rawObject[dp.nameOnServer] = entities.map(function (co) { return unwrapInstance(co); });
            }
        } else if (dp.isDataProperty) {
            val = entity.getProperty(dp.name);
            val = transformValue(val, dp);
            if (val !== undefined) {
                rawObject[dp.nameOnServer] = val;
            }
        }
    });

    stype.navigationProperties.forEach(function (np) {
        if (np.isScalar) {
            // Doesn't occur with products, enabling this results in an endless loop without checking if the navigation property already exists in the rawObject (recursive..)
            // rawObject[np.nameOnServer] = unwrapInstance(entity.getProperty(np.name));
        } else {
            entities = entity.getProperty(np.name);
            rawObject[np.nameOnServer] = entities.map(function (eo) { return unwrapInstance(eo); });
        }
    });

    return rawObject;
}
function transformValue(val, prop) {
    if (prop.isUnmapped) return;
    if (prop.dataType === breeze.DataType.DateTimeOffset) {
        // The datajs lib tries to treat client dateTimes that are defined as DateTimeOffset on the server differently
        // from other dateTimes. This fix compensates before the save.
        val = val && new Date(val.getTime() - (val.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));
    } else if (prop.dataType.quoteJsonOData) {
        val = val != null ? val.toString() : val;
    }
    return val;
}
```